# How to output ${expression} in FreeMarker that contains HTML AS HTML

Tags: freemarker

In my data model myVar contains `<b>hello</b>` and when I bring it like this `${myVar}` the output I get is literally `<b>hello</b>` rather than **hello**.

Any idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you have HTML escaping on, so try `<#noescape>${myvar}</#noescape>`.

**Update:** Since 2.3.24 a new kind of auto-escaping was introduced, which doesn't use `#escape`, and hence nor `#noescape`. When that's used, write `${myvar?no_esc}` to avoid escaping. Or, you can put the value into the data-model already as a `TemplateHTMLOutputModel` (created with `HTMLOutputFormat.fromMarkup(myString)`), and then FreeMarker will know without `?no_esc` that it need not be escaped.